# Canvas load identity or save for multiple restores

Tags: android, canvas, matrix

The following works :

```
        canvas.save();
        canvas.translate(s.startLine[2], s.startLine[3]);
        canvas.rotate(-90);
        canvas.drawText(s.startTimeString, 0, 0, darkPaint);
        canvas.restore();
        canvas.save(); \\ redundant?
        canvas.rotate(-90);
        canvas.translate(s.endLine[2],s.endLine[3]);
        canvas.drawText(s.endTimeString,0,0,darkPaint);
        canvas.restore();
```

Is this the most perfomant way to do what i want? I mean this second save() seem redundant to me... I thought that removing it would make restore restore the matrix state to the latest saved state but unfortunately i got this exception :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Underflow in restore - more restores than saves
```

Is there a better approach? note that the canvas matrix is never change in my drawing other to this part, so maybe loading the identity matrix could also be an option, but i am not sure if its better...

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#restore()):

> **void restore ()**
>
> This call balances a previous call to save(), and is used to remove all modifications to the matrix/clip state since the last save call. **It is an error to call restore() more times than save() was called.**

So the error you are getting is consistent with the documentation.

You may want to take a look at the `restoreToCount` method ([documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#restoreToCount(int))):

> **void restoreToCount (int saveCount)**
>
> Efficient way to pop any calls to save() that happened after the save count reached saveCount.
>
> ...

You propose loading the identity matrix as a way to undo. I would not do it not because of the performance but because you are trying to undo (restore) some changes adding more changes to the stack.